# A number changing by two buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, label

I want a Label that increases by 1 if I click on Button `+` and decreases by clicking on button `-`. Here's my code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="+" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="-" />
```

and

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int n = 0;

...

       n--;
       Label1.Text = n.ToString();

 and 

       n++;
       Label1.Text = n.ToString();
```

But they don't work. What is the problem ?

Comment: use field instead of local variable. i suspect that you declare `n` inside method.

Comment: Please show your code with some more context

Comment: Yes more context and more detail. "doesn't work" really isn't helpful, how does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because that you have declared n as a field of the page class,like this:

```
public class DefaultPage:Page
{
    int n;
}
```

You need to understand that the page class get a new instance in every request.So the filed "n" can't  keep the value,because they are owned by diffrent instance.

You can try to get the old value from the Label1 control of the page:

```
int n=int.Parse(Label1.Text);
n--;
Label1.Text = n.ToString();
```

If you want to use this code, pay attention to ensure that the Text property of the Label1 is a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in a ViewState variable.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ViewState["Clicks"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["Clicks"] = 0;
            }
            Label1.Text = ViewState["Clicks"].ToString();
        }
    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ClicksCount = (int)ViewState["Clicks"] + 1;
        Label1.Text = ClicksCount.ToString();
        ViewState["Clicks"] = ClicksCount;
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ClicksCount = (int)ViewState["Clicks"] - 1;
        Label1.Text = ClicksCount.ToString();
        ViewState["Clicks"] = ClicksCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why it's not working. What is the problem ?

In your `WebForm1` class, `n` is an instance variable which gets re-initialized when an instance of your class is created. When the page loads it gets initialized  to `0`, now when you click `Button1` postback happends you class is re-initialized and `n` is initialized to `0`, then in `Button1_Click` event you increment it by 1 using `n++`, so you are able to see `1`. When you again click the button, again a new instance of class is created and `n` is again initialized to `0`. This is how it works, thus you are not able to see the expected output.

> How can I fix this?

You will have to pick any of the [State Management Techniques](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx). You can make use of `Hidden variable` or `ViewState` here. @ChrisRun has already demonstrated how to do this with `ViewState`. This is how you can do it with Hidden Variable:-

Declare a hidden variable with initial value as `0`:-

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="NumHidden" runat="server" Value="0" />
```

Code Behind:-

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  int n = 0;
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n = int.Parse(NumHidden.Value);
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n++;
        Label1.Text = NumHidden.Value = n.ToString();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n--;
        Label1.Text = NumHidden.Value = n.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It didn't help. Test it yourself.

Comment: @user1448393 - I did and it's working perfectly for me. What issue you are facing?